# override default css in new theme in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I did create custom.css in app/design/frontend/hsc/hsc-theme/web/css. But it didn't work how to do it?
How to override default css in new theme in magento 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customise the CSS you simply override the .LESS file where the original styles you want to change exist, using the equivalent name/path in your own theme. So for example if you wanted to override the checkout CSS, originally defined in the following file: **app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Checkout/web/css/ source/_module.less**

You would copy the contents of this file and create a new file in your own theme with the same path. So, it would look something like this: **app/design/frontend/hsc/hsc-theme/web/css/source/_module.less**

Also make sure your theme is activate from Magento 2 backend **Content > Design > Themes**.

Thanks